# Type Hinting - декоратор, возвращающий функцию, которая возвращает генератор типа

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы

Доброе время суток.

Вопрос описанию функций.

Есть фукция, которая делает запрос и возвращает объект типа

```
def _get(...) -> JsonResponseData:
    ...
    return JsonResponseData(...)
```

Есть декоратор, который изменяет логику поведения, передавая параметры в выше указанную функцию. Он смотрит на данные, и пока они есть частями делаем запросы и получает данные.

```
def decorator_excample(func: Callable[..., T], offset: int, limit: int) -> Callable[..., Generator[T]]:
    def wrapper(...):
        ...
    return wrapper
```

В IDE в результате выполнения функции, изменненной этим декоратором, тип обозначается как Any.

```
@decorator_example
def _get(...) -> JsonResponseData:
    ...
    return JsonResponseData(...)


for x in _get(offset=0, limit=100):
   x #  <-- пишет, что тип Any
   x: JsonResponseData  # <- Хот фикс, но это плохо
```

Как сделать, чтобы тип был тот, что возвращается у исходной функции?

---

Используется Python 3.9

Добавлю больше информации, если потребуется

Comment: Для начала наверное нормально проаннотируйте декоратор с помощью [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) (но для Python 3.9 видимо придётся ставить typing_extensions)

Comment: И да, [Generator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) принимает три параметра, а вы указали один, и это неправильно. Возможно, в данном конкретном случае лучше просто использовать [Iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterator) (или Iterable, точно не знаю)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую